# How to make this query run faster

Tags: php, mysql, performance, select, count

I would like to know if this query can run faster or how to make it faster if possible.

```
$result = mysql_query("select
(select count(1) FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '%Cars%')as Cars,
(select count(1) FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '%Bikes%') as 'Bikes',
(select count(1) FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '%Airplanes%') as 'Airplanes',
(select count(1) FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '%Trucks%') as 'Trucks',
(select count(1) FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '%Games%') as 'Games'");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

foreach($row as $title => $total)
{
  echo '<li>
<a href="search.php?search='. $title . '&submit= ">'. $title.'&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $total .'</a></li>';
}

echo '<li class="spaceIN"></li><li class="letter">A</li>';
```

I make a copy of this script and paste it like 100 times and it is really slow loading after doing that.

Comment: If the ratio `SELECT` queries over `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` is big, you can store these counters in a separate table, and update them when you update `videos` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```
select sum(title LIKE '%Cars%') as cars,
       sum(title LIKE '%Bikes%') as bikes
from videos
```

Comment: Thank you this is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the SQL suggestions in other answers - how about rather than having that query run every time someone visits that page (assuming that's what happens) - instead store counts in the database and have a Cron job run the script to update them at regular intervals in the background. Then query the stored count on that page - which will obviously be considerably faster

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your inline queries in the `select` list with `sum` functions over boolean expressions:

```
SELECT SUM (title LIKE '%Cars%') as Cars,
       SUM (title LIKE '%Bikes%') as 'Bikes',
       SUM (title LIKE '%Airplanes%') as 'Airplanes',
       SUM (title LIKE '%Trucks%') as 'Trucks',
       SUM (title LIKE '%Games%') as 'Games'
FROM   videos
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a category column, int or enum, depends on how often you add/change categories. You could use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c, category FROM videos GROUP BY category;
```

then. Waaaay better to have defined categories than having to do string stuff on every query. Also '%' in the beginning is slow as hell as it can't use indexes.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer. But why is '%' slow, should i delete that ?

Comment: **why is '%' slow** well if you had to read every character in a book to locate each sentence containing 'car' would that be slower then flipping to the index to find CAR?